Analyzing Performance Differences in Assembly Code on x64 Architecture
comparing these two assembly instructions generated by compiler:
1.
mov    ebx, 1
cmp    edi, ebx
jl    SHORT $LN3@main
npad    7

$LL4@main:
mov    eax, edi
cdq
idiv    ebx
test    edx, edx
je    SHORT $LN61@main

$LN2@main:
inc    ebx
cmp    ebx, edi
jle    SHORT $LL4@main

$LN3@main:




mov    ebx, 1
cmp    rbx, rdi
ja    SHORT $LN3@main
npad    4

$LL4@main:
xor    edx, edx
mov    rax, rdi
div    rbx
test    rdx, rdx
je    SHORT $LN61@main

$LN2@main:
inc    rbx
cmp    rbx, rdi
jbe    SHORT $LL4@main

$LN3@main:

The first set of instructions executes 70% faster on my x64 machine (11th generation Intel). Any idea why?
These instructions are generated for the following code:
for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i) {
        if (number % i == 0) {
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
        }
    }

In the second set of instructions, I changed int to uint64_t. When number is a large 32-bit integer (treated as uint64_t in the second set, although using int64_t yields the same result), I expected the performance to be equal on a 64-bit machine. Also, on my older Ivybridge machine, the first set executes three times faster!

division is an expensive instruction in both time and latency in x64 mode. But +,- and * have roughly equal timing on modern hardware. I think you will find that is at the root of your problem. Try summing i*i instead and I reckon the speeds will be very similar.

I also thought division was the root of the problem. However, I believe the timing is equal on an x64 machine (11th Gen Intel), but the latency is higher.

According to Agners tables the difference in speed you see on Ivybridge is plausible for the integer divide being the root cause r32 vs x64 operands.

Second data point: uops.info gives one div R64 every 10 cycles and one idiv R32 every 6 cycle. Note that division is one of the few instructions that are data-dependent in their runtime.

On Ice Lake and later, and on AMD, idiv r64 and idiv r32 are the same speed for the same numbers.  On earlier Intel, 64-bit operand-size is much slower, microcoded as more uops.  See Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux for details.  "11th Generation" includes some Ice Lake / Tiger Lake but also some Skylake-derived CPUs like Comet Lake; it's not a very specific way to describe a microarchitecture since Intel marketing kept attaching overlapping generation numbers to respins of the same old uarch.
